# Xenmobile iOS swift 3 import worxxenable

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, citrix

I'm trying to make an iOS app that needs to use feature unique to Citrix Zenmobile framework. **My problem** however is that the import of that framework doesn't seem to work when I try to import these Objective-C libraries :

```
import AVFoundation
import SystemConfiguration.SCNetworkReachability
import Worx.WorxEnable //<---- causes this error no such module
```

I've imported it in this way:
[image: General tab in the project]

and included the files in the project like this:

[image: Project structure]

I'm at loss to what I could do to make this important import work. I'm even considering going back and remaking what I have done so far in objective-C instead. Even though that would require me to learn a new language.

**Edit:**

I created a header file that I called Work-Bridging-Header.h and inside that I pasted the lines

```
//import MDX extensions
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SCNetworkReachability.h>
#import <Worx/WorxEnable.h>
```

in to it.

I went to the project build settings and added the path to the worx-bridging-header.h to the swift compiler under the Objective-C Bridging Header I did this in both debug and release not sure it is needed in both I'm just assuming it is.

however I'm back to the original problem

When I write :

```
//import MDX extensions
import AVFoundation
import SystemConfiguration.SCNetworkReachability
import Worx.WorxEnable
```

the issue is still with the Worx.WorxEnable. even if I only use Worx or WorxEnable without the others...

Comment: Same message when I do that as well as if I only try to write import WorxEnable

Comment: have you add bridging file into your project?

Comment: As you said that this framework is created in Objective-C you will have to create a bridging header and import that framework in it and then you can import it in other files.

Comment: oh I was under the assumption that was only applied to my own frameworks not others. 

that when I imported a framework Xcode would automatically create a bridging header. 
I'm going to try that then now. Being new to swift as well this is quite tough to get my head around :)

Comment: have you add this line into bridging file"#import "Worx/WorxEnable.h" ??please add it and do deep clean your project  and then make build or run

Comment: I made the bridging-header file now it seems to be working Thanks a lot. took me some time to figure out how to manually do this part most online places only described how it should pop up with a creation of this automatically. must have answered without realising what I was answering on.

Comment: if none of you will post a direct answer I'll allocate my solution as the answer to my own question :) I do however think that one of you guys should get the credits for leading me in to the solution

Comment: was too early removed the error but placed it in another place now :(

Comment: And After fixing those I'm back to square one same line causes the same error...

Comment: I think I found a way to solve this but not sure. 

The bridging header means I do not need to import in individual classes ? or am I wrong here ?